# how do i get django cms editor to work inside djangos default tags

Tags: django, django-cms

I am building a django app that would allow users to create html content (to be used as an email template), but keep getting TemplateSyntaxError.

I am trying to use the django-cms plugins in my own view and templates any ideas.

```html
{% extends 'admin/merchant/base.html' %}
{% load cache %}
{% load cms_tags %}
    
{% block extra_head %}
    {% placeholder "css" %}
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block content %}
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}

        {% placeholder "content" or %} Nothing is coming through... {% endplaceholder %}
    </body>
{% endblock content %}
```

but i get this error:

````
Template error:
In template /home/joel/Projects/Vendora Deploy/src/templates/admin/merchant/newsletter/create-page.html, error at line 15
   Invalid block tag on line 15: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
   5 : {% block extra_head %}
   6 :     {% placeholder "css" %}
   7 : {% endblock extra_head %}
   8 : 
   9 : {% block content %}
   10 :     <body>
   11 :         {% cms_toolbar %}
   12 : 
   13 :         {% placeholder "content" or %} Nothing is coming through... {% endplaceholder %}
   14 :     </body>
   15 :  {% endblock content %} 
   16 : 
   17 : 
   18 : ```


  [1]:[Traceback Image][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkHi9.png
````

Comment: check if content is in ur main template

Comment: Can you share your admin/merchant/base.html ?

Comment: yes i have it in my base.html

Comment: the whole thing? it's over 300 lines long

Comment: @EricMartin basically what i want is to use the cms editing features in that template only while reserving my base navigation and content (if that's at all possible) , all other templates work fine.

Comment: what you can do is share a dpaste.  https://dpaste.org/

Comment: yeah, wow found dpaste extremely useful thanks @VisheshMangla. here's the link [base.html](https://dpaste.org/OzAR)

Comment: {% placeholder %} will only work inside the template’s <body>. Check http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#placeholders

Comment: I know that but the {% placeholder "css" %} works but the {% placeholder "content" %} doesn't even when in the body tag. Is there a way to close terminate the tag?

Comment: Please look at the traceback i posted in the question, it shows the exception at line 15 and django doesn't seem to remember that tag {% endblock %} is default to django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get the functionalities i wanted using iframes in my templates

```html
<iframe src="{% url 'vendor:cms-index' %} width="100%" height="80%" />
```

```py
def cms_index_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
   from cms.page_rendering import _render_welcome_page
   return _render_welcome_page(request)
```

I apologize for posting an answer without the required number of reps. just thought it'd be helpful to someone else